# $n$ girls and $n$ boys are sitting around a table. We choose one. Let $X$ be the number of girl neighbours . What is $E(X)$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have $n$ girls and $n$ boys sitting around a table. We choose arbitrary one. Let $X$ be the number of girl neighbours of the chosen one. What is $E(X)$?

Is this correct? Let $L/R$ be $1$ if left/right neighbour is girl and $0$ if not. Then $X = L+R$ and $E(X) = E(L)+E(R) = {1\over 2}+ {1\over 2} =1$. Or should I also take in a consideration a gender of chosen one?

Let $Y$ be $1$ if chosen one is boy and other vise $0$. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(L=1) &=& P(Y=1)\cdot P(L=1|Y=1)+P(Y=0)\cdot P(L=1|Y=0)\\
       &=& {1\over 2} \cdot {n\over 2n-1}+ {1\over 2} \cdot {n-1\over 2n-1}\\
       &=& {1\over 2} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: It's correct.  And taking the gender into account comes to the same answer:  $E=\frac 12 \times 2\times \frac {n-1}{2n-1}+\frac 12 \times 2\times \frac {n}{2n-1}=1$

Comment: @lulu Why did you multiply it by 2?

Comment: Because you have two sides, left and right.

Comment: Ahh, then it is essential the same as my calculation for $P(L=1)$.

Comment: It's exactly the same, just working with the conditional cases based on gender.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct for $n\ge2$. You can tell that the gender of the chosen person is irrelevant by observing that the problem can be re-stated it in a way that excludes the chosen person:

- We have $n$ girls and $n$ boys sitting around a table. We choose a person arbitrarily. We also choose the person two places to the right. Let $X$ be the number of chosen girls. What is $E(X)$?

However, always remember to check for the edge cases. $E(X)$ is not defined for $n=0$, so you don't have to worry about that, but it *is* defined for $n=1$. In that case, the left and the right neighbour are one and the same, so $X=L=R$, there is no sense in adding $E(L)$ and $E(R)$.

Comment: This is brilliant! So I should look for a reformulation of the problem. Thanks. Anyway, Can you take a look at my calculation of $P(L=1)$?

Comment: @ChristianF I may be misreading, but I think you have $P(L=1|Y=1)$ and $P(L=1|Y=0)$ the wrong way around. It's the former that's $n-1\over 2n-1$, and the latter that's $n\over 2n-1$. But it doesn't affect the result.